# tomcat-users.xml credentials are not recognized, Invalid password/token for user in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, credentials

I am trying to deploy a WAR on the remote Tomcat (Remote Machine) using Jenkins deploy to container Plugin. I have done the following configuration in tomcat-users.xml and restarted tomcat and tried to connect using the credentials, but it says invalid password.  How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from your errorlog:

```
The username and password you provided are not correct
```

Could you double-check your credentials?

Comment: Hi Luc, I checked multiple times :(

Comment: Are you able to connect to  http://jjtest:8080/manager/text/list using these credentials?

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved after installing  tomcat manager by

```
sudo yum install tomcat-webapps tomcat-admin-webapps
```